# How to solve a system of equation with Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

How can I go ahead solving this equation ?

1. $2x = \lambda(10x + 6y)$
2. $2y  = \lambda(10y + 6x)$
3. $5x^2 + 6xy + 5y^2 = 1$

My attempt was dividing number $1$ by number two. Eliminating the Lagrange multiplier, and then solving for $x$ and $y$. But that did not work. Do you have any advice or any simpler methods for solving this system of equation?

Comment: What is an original problem? I think using LM here is very ugly and unnecessarily.

Comment: The original problem is to use the Lagrange method to find the closest and farthest point to origin, with the constraint 5x^2 + 6xy + 5y^2 = 1

Comment: Taking advantage of the equations’ symmetry, you might guess that interesting things happen when $x=y$ or $x=-y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would usually solve for $\lambda$ and equate the two values of $\lambda$ which gives
$$\frac{2x}{10x+6y}=\frac{2y}{10y+6x}(=\lambda)$$
$$x(5y+3x)=y(5x+3y)$$
$$5xy+3x^2=5xy+3y^2$$
$$x^2=y^2$$
$$y=\pm x$$
Hence the last equation is
$$10x^2\pm6x^2=1$$
$$4x^2,16x^2=1$$
$$x^2=\frac14,\frac1{16}$$
$$x=\pm\frac12,\pm\frac14$$
Hence solutions are
$$(\frac12,\frac12),(\frac12,-\frac12),(\frac14,\frac14),(\frac14,-\frac14),(-\frac12,\frac12),(-\frac12,-\frac12),(-\frac14,\frac14),(-\frac14,-\frac14),$$

Comment: Nice! I see. I will note this. I didn't realize that I could do this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{5x+3y}{5y+3x}$$ or
$$x^2=y^2,$$ which gives $x=y$ or $x=-y.$

Can you end it now?

The original problem you can solve without LM:
$$2(x^2+y^2)\leq5x^2+6xy+5y^2\leq8(x^2+y^2),$$
which gives
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: @Peter Foreman :)

Comment: Yes, thanks to you and Peter Foreman.

Comment: @dondeman You are welcome! See my solution without LM.